# Initialize all fields in class with type based constructor

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a small problem with the initalization of a class that is basically the central access point for some data storage.

It is not really a "problem" but I am looking for a way to write it in a elegant way.

I have a class with a large amount of fields. Each field is set as `ReadOnly` and is initializied inside the constructor. Now I'd like a way to init all fields in this class without writing the constructor in a explicit way. Mainly because the constructor is in matters of the used parameters always the same and for each initializiation is some error checking required. Also the nature of the created instances allow me to run those parallel and I'd like to do just that.

Now I created some nice construct that works... kind of:

```
  Dim myType = [GetType]()
  Dim fields = myType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
  Dim flags = BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance
  Dim culture = Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
  Dim params() As Object = {param1, param2, param3}

  Task.WaitAll((From field In fields
                Where GetType(ISomeInterface).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType)
                Select Task.Run(Sub()
                                  Try
                                    Dim newInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(field.FieldType, flags, Nothing, params, culture)
                                    field.SetValue(Me, newInstance)
                                  Catch ex As Exception
                                    ReportError(ex)
                                  End Try
                                End Sub)).ToArray)
```

This thing works. How ever there are two issues:

First thing is that it feels like a hack. I am setting read only fields from a lambda expression that is like a internal class. So I am basically setting read only fields from outside the class. That just feels wrong and that may cause problems in future releases of .NET.

Second problem is that this code is run though a obfuscator. And this obfuscator has the bright idea of change all the field types to `Object` causing the entire thing to stop working. I was yet unable to get the obfuscator to leave those fields alone. But that is not the issue here. It only showns how prone to errors this entire construct is.

Is there any "nicer" way to initialize those fields?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I'd like a way to init all fields in this class without writing the constructor in a explicit way.

Are you looking for something like this in VB.NET's syntax?

```
Public Class MyClassWithReadOnlyProperties
  Public ReadOnly Property MyProperty1 As String = "Hello"
  Public ReadOnly Property MyProperty2 As Integer = 1
End Class
```

I think it's coming as part of Visual Studio "14", which is currently at CTP4.

You can, however, do this with fields in VS 2013, just not yet properties:

```
Public Class MyClassWithReadOnlyProperties
  Public ReadOnly MyProperty1 As String = "Hello"
  Public ReadOnly MyProperty2 As Integer = 1
End Class
```

Yes, using reflection is a hack, and should only be used as last resort.

Comment: Problem is that my initialization of a single property requires some error checking. And that fails in case I use such direct assignment. I was looking for a way to get this done without writing this error checking around every single field I need to initialize.

Comment: @Nitram: Can you add the dummy code you are trying to improve? Please add a sample class declaration to your question with, say, 3 properties, to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a Factory method?

```
Class DemoClass
  Property Prop1 As String
  Property Prop2 As String
  Property Prop3 As String

  Sub New(p1 As String, p2 As String, p3 As String)
    Prop1 = p1
    Prop2 = p2
    Prop3 = p3
  End Sub

  Enum DemoClassTypes_ENUM As Integer
    Dog
    Cat
    Sheep
  End Enum

  Shared Function Factory(classType As DemoClassTypes_ENUM) As DemoClass
    Select Case classType 
      Case DemoClassTypes_ENUM.Cat
        Return New DemoClass("Felix", "Meow", "4") 'Could return a subclass here if you wanted
      Case DemoClassTypes_ENUM.Dog
        Return New DemoClass("Rex", "Woof", "4")
      Case DemoClassTypes_ENUM.Sheep
        Return New DemoClass("Dolly", "Baa", "4")
    End Select
    Return Nothing
  End Function

End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim c As DemoClass = DemoClass.Factory(DemoClass.DemoClassTypes_ENUM.Cat)
```